# subprocess.run leads to space interpreted as arg?

Tags: python, testing, subprocess

I'm writing an extremely simple test suite, and when I call `subprocess.run(["./name-of-binary", args],  capture_output=True, shell=True)`, it stores the output of the command. When I call that with `args = ""`, it seems to pass a space to the binary. When I run the binary with an actual space, everything works totally normally. What's going on? Thanks!

Comment: If you pass a list, you shouldn't use `shell=True`

Comment: @jizhihaoSAMA huh, that still seems to pass a space. That fixed the issues with my other run calls, but not the space issue

Comment: Have you tried to remove the args when `args = ""`?

Comment: @jizhihaoSAMA That does work. Also the answer you posted (and then deleted apparently?) worked fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possible Solution(Recommend):

```
if args:
    subprocess.run(["./name-of-binary"],  capture_output=True)
else:
    subprocess.run(["./name-of-binary", args],  capture_output=True)
```

Or:

```
subprocess.run("".join(["./name-of-binary", args]),  capture_output=True, shell=True) # this maybe will cause shell injection.
```

I think the cause is that when execute this command, `subprocess` will add space automatically between those element.So the direct way is to pass string directly.